# How do I save my JScrollPane position after I do a JFrame.pack()?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jscrollpane

I have the following code:

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(new panel(with stuff in it));
frame.getContentPane().add(scrollPane);
```

So the user scrolls a bit and then clicks a link on my panel and then I do a pack(), so I try the following code:

```
int val = scrollPane.getVerticalScrollBar().getValue();
frame.pack();
scrollPane.getVerticalScrollBar().setValue(val);
```

But this code still returns my scrollBar back to the beginning instead of keeping the position it was originally at before the pack.  Any ideas would be appreciated, Thanks!

Comment: What does your `int val` hold? Is it the correct value?  Does it work without a pack?

Comment: @jzd : Yes val holds the correct value, and it does work without the pack.

Comment: Post your SSCCE (http://sscce.org) demonstrating the problem.

Comment: curious: why would you do a pack()?

Comment: just asking .. won't the frame.pack() will ignore the positioning of scrollBar

Comment: @kleopatra : I need to resize because I'm adding components to my frame

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try wrapping the setValue() method in a SwingUtilities.invokeLater().